# ¿Se puede hacer una referencia a una dll (framework 4) desde mi proyecto vs 2005(framework 2)?

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

Una consulta, estoy trabajando en un proyecto en vs 2005(framework 2), y creado una Biblioteca de clases en vs 2013 (framework 4), y esta genera una dll. ¿ Se puede desde mi proyecto vb 2005 hacer referencia a esa dll?

Agradecería sus repuestas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, no se puede.

Tendrás que cambiar la dll que has hecho en VS 2013 a framework 2.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta,, pero lo que pasa es que la biblioteca de clases (framework 4),, tiene referencias que solo hay framework 4.

Comment: Pues el otro camino... cambiar lo que estas haciendo en framework 2 al framework 4